# Delay sending an email using Mandrill send_at or Celery countdown/eta

Tags: python, django, celery, delayed-job, mandrill

I commonly send transactional emails in response to certain actions on my website, some of which I delay sending by a couple of hours.  The function that actually queues the email is a Celery task function called with `.delay()` that eventually makes an API call to Mandrill using [`djrill`](https://djrill.readthedocs.org/en/v1.4/).

I discovered that Mandrill offers a [`send_at`](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582667-Can-I-schedule-a-message-to-send-at-a-specific-time-) parameter when sending an email that will have Mandrill delay sending the email until the specified time.  Celery also offers `eta` or `countdown` parameters when calling [`apply_async()` or `delay()`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async) on a task, which will have the Celery worker wait X amount of time before executing the task—which here, would amount to the same thing.

Ignoring cost, which approach is architecturally preferable—having Celery delay queuing the email using `countdown`, or sending the email to Mandrill immediately but with a `send_at` parameter so Mandrill waits for me?  What factors should I be considering when making this decision?

Comment: You're essentially asking, should you keep scheduled email in your own queue or in Mandrill's? That's almost more an ops question: are you more comfortable offloading mail queue maintenance to Mandrill, or keeping it integrated with the Celery system you're (presumably) already using for other things. Seems like switching cost wouldn't be high, so maybe try it both ways and see which you prefer.

Comment: One other thing: if there's some reason you need the Mandrill message id assigned at the time you're _scheduling_ the message, then you'd have to go with Mandrill's send_at.

Comment: I've done both; and you are completely right that switching cost is low.  I've more been wondering what am I missing thinking about when contemplating this--and it sounds like potentially not much.

Answer (score 0):

I'll share some points we could have into account to make a choice here:

1. **Fault tolerance**: if we give this responsibility to Celery, then we could be more prone to fails, since if the message queue (Rabbitmq, ZeroMQ or whatever ), the machine or the Celery itself fails then the email will never be sent. Mandrill could fails as well, but probably in minor grade.
2. **Maintenance**: What about if you need to change Celery for something else? In this case you need to migrate the code and probably, to spend some time to figure out how to do this scheduling in the new MQ tool.
3. **OOP**: From the point of OPP, we might see Mandrill as an entity that sends emails, which brings several features, e.g. scheduling, so let's consume this *external* service from our system, let it do it its work!
4. **Usability and Scalability**: Think on an hypothetical situation where you need to run your system in more than one server simultaneously, due to growing performance requirements; which is the easier and more efficient way to handle this scheduling?

These are not all the aspects that should be considered to make a decision, but certainly are some that should not be missed. Hope that helps to figure a better/solid solution.